# Makefile allegro-nasm

Tags: c, makefile, nasm, allegro

Hi i have to write a code where i'll be combining NASM (assembly) with C and allegro library

```
CC = gcc
OBJ = main.o func.o
BIN = program
CFLAGS = -m32
$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(OBJ) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN) 
main.o: main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.c -o main.o
func.o: func.s
    nasm -f elf func.s
```

how do I add `allegro-confing --libs` here? and where?

Answer (score 1):

Given this makefile, you should add it to the link line:

```
$(BIN): $(OBJ)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN) $(OBJ) `allegro-config --libs`
```